# Is there a PyPlot construct that allows one to configure a portable canvas that does not exist in PyPlot's global workspace?

Tags: matplotlib

I will use the term **canvas** to mean some kind of renderable and complete sub-component/object so I don't confuse anyone by overloading PyPlot terminology.

I am looking for a canvas-like construct that I can pass around in collections and through pipelines and back to PyPlot for rendering. The motivation here is to create reusable functions for generic rendering tasks.  The approaches I have tried so far always end up falling back on the PyPlot global space/object at some point before the plots are ready to be rendered.

E.g., I could create a plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', ...]
y_axis = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', ...]

plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.title('title name')
plt.xlabel('x_axis name')
plt.ylabel('y_axis name')
plt.show()
```

but the "canvas" lives in PyPlot. For example, is there a way to build outside or export the canvas for future rendering?  E.g. ()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...

plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)

...

canvas = plt.export()

... do things ...

plt.show(canvas)
```

More specifically, for example, I wrote the following code to render an array of images. Is there a way to generalize this code by replacing PlotProperties.image with a generic container that can hold an image, scatterplot, or similar graph.?

```
@dataclass
class PlotProperties:
    image: np.array
    caption: str
    color_mode: ColorMode

def render_image_card(plots: List[PlotProperties], title: str, gallery_columns: int = 3, font_size: int = 10) -> None:
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': f'{font_size}'})
    plt.figure(0, figsize=(5 + gallery_columns, 4))  # width / height
    grid_size = (2, gallery_columns + 2)  # height / width
    ax = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
    poster = plots.pop(0)
    colormapping = 'gray' if poster.color_mode == ColorMode.GRAYSCALE else 'viridis'
    ax.imshow(poster.image, cmap=colormapping)
    plt.title(poster.caption)

    for index, plot in enumerate(plots):
        x = index % gallery_columns
        y = index // gallery_columns
        ax_inner = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (0 + y, 2 + x))
        colormapping = 'gray' if poster.color_mode == ColorMode.GRAYSCALE else 'viridis'
        ax_inner.imshow(plot.image, cmap=colormapping)
        plt.title(plot.caption)

    forceAspect(ax, aspect=1)
    plt.suptitle(title)
    hide_tick_labels(plt.gcf())
```

I have tried using figures, but I always have a problem where I need to go back to `plt` to deal with specific formatting.  What am I missing?

Comment: Yours *sounds* like an interesting question, so I wonder why no answers. Because of a certain vagueness, maybe? Could you be more precise and describe what you really want to do? That said, you can do a lot of work using a `Figure` without touching the `pyplot` namespace, but no one can tell you what to do if you dont' tell us what you want to do.

Comment: @gboffi Thank you. I will come up with some specific scenarios and update the question.

Comment: @gboffi I created an example that may be interesting.